# Nano RP2040 Connect with Wired Ethernet. Do I lose IoT functionality and OTA updates? Any suggestions?

Tags: arduino-nano-rp2040

So, we have a project that is developing nicely on the RP2040, and currently uses WiFi. However, a new use-case is emerging where it may need to be in a noisy industrial environment. As such it makes sense for it to be physically connected (ethernet) rather than wifi (industrial environments can be very noisy, and not every factory has a full high quality wifi).
I know there are SPI modules such as a board based on the W5500 chipset, but they beg questions:

1. will I lose the IoT and OTA update capability this way?
2. Can I get PoE via a module as well, so my customers have an easier installation?
   The RP2040 is an ideal unit for us - IoT and OTA updates, with huge flash as well, so I'm not sure there's a sensible alternative (unless anyone can suggest one!). Everything else we need is in the arduino libraries as well, so that is also a great fit for us.

Comment: `lose IoT functionality` ... what does this mean?